# Partial search query in kuromoji

Tags: elasticsearch, kuromoji

I have an issue when trying to do partial search using the kuromoji plugin.

When I index full sentence, like `ホワイトソックス` with analyzer like:

```
{
  "tokenizer": {
    "type": "kuromoji_tokenizer",
    "mode": "search"
  },
  "filter": ["lowercase"],
  "text" : "ホワイトソックス"
}
```

then the word is properly split into `ホワイト` and `ソックス` as it should, I can search for both words separately, and that's correct.

**But**, when user didn't provide full sentence yet and is missing last letter (`ホワイトソック`), any kuromoji analyzer treats it as one word.
Because of that, result is empty.

My question is, is there something I can do about it? Either by indexing or searching this query in different fashion? I'm sure there is japan partial search but I can't find the right settings.

Example index settings:

```
{
    analyzer: {
        ngram_analyzer: {
            tokenizer: 'search_tokenizer',
            filter: ['lowercase', 'cjk_width', 'ngram_filter'],
        },
        search_analyzer: {
            tokenizer: 'search_tokenizer',
            filter: ['asciifolding'],
        }
    },
    filter: {
        ngram_filter: {
            type: 'edge_ngram',
            min_gram: '1',
            max_gram: '20',
            preserve_original: true,
            token_chars: ['letter', 'digit']
        }
    },
    tokenizer: {
        search_tokenizer: {
            type: 'kuromoji_tokenizer',
            mode: 'search'
        }
    }
}
```

Search query:

```
query_string: {
    fields: [
       "..."
    ],
    query: "ホワイトソック",
    fuzziness: "0",
    default_operator: "AND",
    analyzer: "search_analyzer"
 }
```

Any help appreciated!